# angular2 connect to browser websql

Tags: angular, web-sql

I have angular 2 app that in the end should be mobile and desktop app.
( I use node.js)

I want to use websql of the browser as my db.

how can I create tables in websql , update them if needed and perform query on them ? 
I tried several plugins without success ):

when my app load I want to check if DB exit and is up to date, if it is I want to use it.
If it isn't I want to update it from local json file and then use it .

thanks 
Tami

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB is the successor to WebSQL. Have a look at the Ngrx libraries, they have a nice wrapper for it.

https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

Comment: I need to use websql , cannot use Indexed